# Update existing schema using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying change existing schema to add new column.

Here is my case - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06c58/1

Value of `Order` column is int, which should represent order of items on UI from 1 to `COUNT(Id)` if I'm grouping `TemplateId`.

I see 2 possible solutions - make `Order` calculated field or use Cursor to update it.

Which one is better? And if update using cursor win -

May I know how to have such update ?

Comment: What's the end use of the Order column? A report which also shows Order?

Comment: No, Order is technical column. It will never be shown on UI or reposts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of it is this:

1. Start a transaction
2. Insert into columns apart from Order
3. Update the table to set Order values
4. Commit transaction if everything is OK, else rollback.

You won't need to directly deal with cursors to do this, and the operation will be atomic in a way, since it's wrapped in a transaction block.

The update itself can be done something like this:

```
;with ord as 
(Select id, row_number() over (partition by templateid order by selectedfieldid) rn from yourtable)
Update dbo.titlefields
Set order = rn - 1 --ROW_NUMBER() starts at 1 but we want to start at 0
From dbo.titlefields t inner join
ord x on t.id = x.id
```

Please let me know if I have understood your requirement correctly, and I will update my answer if that is not so.

Comment: This is the way how to achieve it, but I'm looking for a solution how to calculate values for [Order]

Comment: Here what I have - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab070/13 and here - what I want to get - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88375/1

Comment: OK, I have edited my code to suit your requirement. Do let me know how it works out.